# How to use useRef to toggle between images

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given an image gallery, where the user can click an image and the selected image will be shown in the gallery below it, how can I use `useRef` to replace the image in the gallery div with the selected image on click? The idea is that the images will be populating the gallery at the top from an array, so each image will presumably have the `useRef` applied to it?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imageurl" alt="water" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imageurl2" alt="tree" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imageurl3" alt="snow" style="width:100%" onClick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imageurl4" alt="mountain" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="imageurl5" alt="tree2" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
    <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
    <div id="imgtext"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Function to toggle large image visibility**

```
const myFunction = imgs => {
  const imageRef = useRef();
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

The current state can be seen here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt5uq6na/2/)

Answer (score 2):

As the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) state: **Don’t Overuse Refs**

Your code snippet is not what `ref`s should be used for. In React, you should make things interactive via state changes, not by fiddling with the DOM, React is designed to do that for you.

However from that jsfiddle, it looks like you aren't even using React? I am unsure why you are using `useRef` at all?

---

UPDATE: Code fix

By using `function` to define your function (instead of an arrow function), it gets hoisted so your HTML elements can pick it up, and the `getElementById` method gets you the element reference you need.

Just replace all your js with:

```js
var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");

function myFunction(imgs)  {
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

...and your jsfiddle works.